# Switch records in database

Tags: mysql

What i want to do is switch values of records in database. Here is an example:

```
+--------------+--------- +-------------------+
|ingredient_id | quantity | preferred_measure |
+--------------+----------+-------------------+
|           40 |     5.00 | tbsp              |
|           28 |     5.00 | tsp               |
+--------------+----------+-------------------+
```

What i want to do is to change preferred_measure and just switch them to look like this:

```
+--------------+--------- +-------------------+
|ingredient_id | quantity | preferred_measure |
+--------------+----------+-------------------+
|           40 |     5.00 | tsp               |
|           28 |     5.00 | tbsp              |
+--------------+----------+-------------------+
```

If i change just one then i will have same values for all records and i wouldn't be able to find records that need to be changed to other value because all will be same.

Keep in mind, count of these records in database is 10k+.

To clarify a little bit, preferred_measure is type of enum('tsp'.'tbsp'), it's not possible to change to some other value then this two.

Comment: Which condition do you use to change the records? You should specify your purpose a little bit more.

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use `UPDATE table SET preferred_measure='tbsp' WHERE ingredient_id=28;` and `UPDATE table SET preferred_measure='tsp' WHERE ingredient_id=40;`?

Comment: Records are added by mistake and switch for one another, now where it should be tsp its tbsp and viceversa. I need to set that to original state.

@rationalboss I expted that kinda question, this is just one example. in bottom of my page i did put that count of there records is 10k+ and i don't want to go manually for each.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't have a proper primary key? Is it too late to just add one?

Comment: If you can't articulate logic for how the switch should happen, then you can't do it.

Comment: switch first value to third one like xxx then replace second value to first one, then replace third one to first again
`UPDATE table_name SET preferred_measure='xxx' WHERE preferred_measure='tbsp';
UPDATE table_name SET preferred_measure='tsp' WHERE preferred_measure='tbsp';
UPDATE table_name SET preferred_measure='xxx' WHERE preferred_measure='tsp';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will only change the both strings:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE SET preferred_measure =
  IF(preferred_measure = 'tsp', 'tbsp',
    IF (preferred_measure = 'tbsp', 'tsp', preferred_measure));
```

you also can use a WHERE to speedup the query:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE SET preferred_measure =
  IF(preferred_measure = 'tsp', 'tbsp',
    IF (preferred_measure = 'tbsp', 'tsp', preferred_measure))
WHERE preferred_measure IN('tbsp','tsp');
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well, we don't know do we!

Comment: This one did the trick, just i was getting error in syntax for second query you wrote, i just changed WHERE clause to be ``WHERE preferred_measure = 'tsp || preferred_measure = 'tbsp'``. And it worked, thanks!